# Is 'Sold Count' a good term

Tags: single-word-requests, programming

I am writing a technical document, and in it I want to refer to **the number of units sold for each product**. I want to make it concise, and 'sold count' comes to mind. Does this term sound right? Are there better alternatives?

Comment: Ask the people who will need to refer to your documentation what they call things, not us.

Comment: sorry about that, it's just that both the client and I are not good at English

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend *sold quantity* (or *quantity sold*) as a standard term, used in ERP software and accounting departments all over.

Answer (score 4):

An abbreviation of *the number of units sold for each products* is simply **number sold** or **units sold**.